# Custom DataGrid Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, custom-controls

I'm writing custom DataGrid control. I have one collection of column headers and other collection of rows, which has collection of cells itself. I want all the cells in the column be the same width (the width of the widest cell). How can i do it?

**Solution:**
Every cell knows the column which keep it. In cell's OnApplyTemplate i use Measure and assign the maximum between column's and cell's width to the colunm. When the whole DataGrid is loaded, i iterate through the cells of each row and assign the width of the column to each cell.